# Adding User Defined Fields in Lookup Screens and Verifying with the Selected Branch

Tags: acumatica

I have added a usrOperatingBranch in the Customer / Business Account Screen. I need it displayed in Lookup in Sales Order Customer Field. 
I added and customized the Attributes for Customer Field. But the field is not appearing. Further I also wish to check with the selected Branch entered during Sales Order Entry.

Is it needed to join BAccountExt with BAccountR ?? How is it to be done ?? Is it necessary to to do Inner Join with the Selected Branch of Sales Order (MatchwithBranch) ??`

```
[PXDefault]
[CustomerActive(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,Where<Customer.type,    IsNotNull, Or<Current<SOOrder.aRDocType>, Equal<ARDocType.noUpdate>, And<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>>>>>),
Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, 
DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName), Filterable = true)]
[PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.acctCD),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.acctName),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.addressLine1),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.addressLine2),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.postalCode),
typeof(PX.Objects.AR.CustomerAttribute.Contact.phone1),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.city),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.countryID),
typeof(PX.Objects.AR.CustomerAttribute.Location.taxRegistrationID),
typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.curyID),
typeof(PX.Objects.AR.CustomerAttribute.Contact.salutation),
typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.customerClassID),
typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.status),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt.usrOperatingBranch))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do a join with your GraphExtension, I would change your reference from PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt.usrOperatingBranch to just BAccountExt.usrOperatingBranch and see if that makes the difference.

Comment: No it still does not work ! Surprisingly, the CustomizeSelector works in the Grid below in the Inventory ID

Comment: The checking with UsrOperatingBranch worked in the Lookup and I could get  a display of only those customers who are of the branch.